# How do i save dynamically in flask static folder in a python package?

Tags: flask, pip, python-3.7

I'm trying to build a python package with flask. I am trying to save matplotlib figures into the  static folder of the flask server but based on what i am reading i cannot save files into the package directories. How do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it is not a good idea to save in your static folder on runtime. You can just create a folder named 'files' and do something like this:

```
import os
FILES_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'files')
.
.
```

and then save your files in FILES_DIR.